# I want to display the list of my card but I got error

Tags: python-2.7

Whenever I want to display my card it gives me error.

I wanted to display it as list.

```
class Card:
   suits = ["H", "D", "C", "S"]
   values = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K","A"]
   def __init__(self, value, suit):
     self.value, self.suit = value, suit
   def __str__(self):
     return self.values[self.value] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit] 

class Deck:
   def __init__(self):
      self.decks = []
      for x in range(13):
        for y in range(4):
           self.decks.append(Cards(x, y))
   def __str__(self):
      return self.decks

   def printcard(self):
      print self.decks

def main():
  n=Deck()
  n.printcard()

Output:
  [<__main__.Card instance at 0x0000000002694388>, <__main__.Card instance at 
  0x00000000026944C8>, <__main__.Card instance at 0x0000000002697C08>, 
  <__main__.Card instance at 0x0000000002697C48>, <__main__.Card instance at 
  0x0000000002697C88>, <__main__.Card instance at 0x0000000002697CC8>]
```

Comment: you have to define a representation of your `Card` class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printing `self.decks` prints the list of the `Cards` objects.

Since you didn't define a `__repr__` method for your `Cards` object (`__str__` method is only useful for conversion to `string`, but conversion to string isn't used when representing a `list` of objects, would only work for `print(self.decks[0])`), you just get the default representation: the object address.

Since you didn't provide your `Cards` class, I created a mockup one with the proper `__repr__` defined:

```
class Card:
   suits = ["H", "D", "C", "S"]
   values = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K","A"]
   def __init__(self, value, suit):
     self.value, self.suit = value, suit
   def __repr__(self):
     return self.values[self.value] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit]

class Deck:
   def __init__(self):
      self.decks = []
      for x in range(13):
        for y in range(4):
           self.decks.append(Card(x, y))

   def printcard(self):
      print(self.decks)

n=Deck()
n.printcard()
```

now I get this result, as expected:

```
[2 of H, 2 of D, 2 of C, 2 of S, 3 of H, 3 of D, 3 of C, 3 of S, 4 of H, 4 of D, 4 of C, 4 of S, 5 of H, 5 of D, 5 of C, 5 of S, 6 of H, 6 of D, 6 of C, 6 of S, 7 of H, 7 of D, 7 of C, 7 of S, 8 of H, 8 of D, 8 of C, 8 of S, 9 of H, 9 of D, 9 of C, 9 of S, T of H, T of D, T of C, T of S, J of H, J of D, J of C, J of S, Q of H, Q of D, Q of C, Q of S, K of H, K of D, K of C, K of S, A of H, A of D, A of C, A of S]
```

Comment: It's okay now.I already display the list of my deck thank you :)

Comment: that looks like a new question. Maybe you can edit your question to add it (using an EDIT: header) ? (be more accurate, because like that it's broad)

Comment: Oh sorry Thank you again :)